# Resolving TypeScript dependencies in yarn workspaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, package.json, monorepo

I'm currently trying to set up a React/TypeScript monorepo with two workspaces, @scope/project-lib and @scope/project-app. I have @scope/project-app's package.json importing `@scope/project-lib: "*"` under dependencies. I *can* get it to work by doing

`import { MyComponent } from @scope/project-lib/build/components/MyComponent`

but consumers are going to use

`import { MyComponent } from @scope/project-lib/components/MyComponent`

after I publish it, so obviously I'd like to use it that way inside the workspace as well.

I referenced the project-lib path in my tsconfig for project-app:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": { "@scope/project-lib/*": ["../project-lib/build/*"] }
    // other config options
  }
```

I also import it into project-app's package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@scope/project-lib": "*",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
```

The odd part is that omitting the /build/ part of the path shows this error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@scope/project-lib/components/MyComponent' in 'path/to/user/folder/scope/packages/project-app/src'`

I don't understand why it's looking in src (or maybe I should be pointing everything as src? But then how does it build TS and JSX on the fly?)

Answer (score 9):

I too have a monorepo with TypeScript + Lerna (w/ Yarn Workspaces) with ~50+ packages.

It is configured to not use the `path` directive, because Yarn Workspaces can automatically detect those and symlink to the package directory in the root `node_modules` folder. That way, it will be as it is any 3rd party package and the `package.json`'s `main`/`module` field will be read and used.

Graphically

```
node_modules/
-- @scope/ -> (this is automatically generated by yarn)
---- foo -> symlink /packages/foo
---- bar -> symlink /packages/bar

packages/
-- foo/
---- dist/ -> built by TypeScript
------ index.js
---- package.json -> contains "main": "dist/index.js"
---- index.ts
---- tsconfig.json
-- bar/
---- package.json -> contains "@scope/foo" as dependency
---- index.ts -> contains "import {baz} from '@scope/foo'"
---- tsconfig.json

package.json
yarn.lock
```

NB. packages must be built at least once before type checking and such, to ensure that their `dist` folder exist

Comment: Maybe "main" in the package.json is the problem. Making the changes you suggest does allow me to do `import { baz } from '@scope/foo'` when baz is defined and exported from index.ts. But I still have issues importing from other directories. Can you specify a directory for "main"?

Comment: @Mogarrr You cannot specify a directory for `main`, but you could with `exports` ; sadly it's still not supported in TS as for today. The 4.3.0-beta is supposed to support it but it's still broken. I've been searching for similar approaches and am still wondering what's the best.

Comment: how is the "@scope" defined?

Comment: @caeus `@scope` is contained in the name of the package (in the package.json). So `packages/foo/package.json` would contain `"name": "@scope/foo`

Comment: Does this way work without Lerna? given the fact that lerna was just recently decomissioned?